# Can't understand why I got these results using struct offset in C

Tags: c, struct, offset

I was playing with structs and trying to get their values using offsets, this is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

typedef struct abcd{
    int a,b;
    double c,d;
}abcd;

int main()
{
    abcd teste = {.a = 3, .b = 5, .c = 7, .d = 9};
    printf("value of a: %d  //value of b:  %d\n",*( (char*) &teste), *((char*) &teste + offsetof(abcd, b)) );
    return 0;
}
```

output: `value of a: 3  //value of b:  5`

everything works fine but when I change the printf to

```
printf("value of a: %d  value of b: %d\n", *( &teste), *((char*) &teste + offsetof(abcd, b)) );
//No casting to (char*) in value of a
```

I get the output: `value of a: 5  value of b: 1360854088`

Why does this happens?

Comment: Your second `printf` you are actually giving a complete structure (`*(&teste)`) for a `%d` format specifier. That's going to misalign the stack locations of subsequent values for subsequent specifiers in the format string.

Comment: @GRC Can you expand on this a little? Casting is a very useful feature if used correctly.

Comment: `printf("value of a: %d  value of b: %d\n", *(int*)( &teste), *(int*)((char*) &teste + offsetof(abcd, b)) );`

Comment: Type casting has a long and honored tradition in C programming, and is necessary for properly using things like `malloc()` that return a `void *` type. I'm not sure what GRC is going on about.

Comment: @larsks In C you are NOT supposed to cast a `void *`, particularly for `malloc`.  A `void *` can be assigned to any non-function pointer type without casting.  C++ is a different story, however.

Comment: @GRC what standard, exactly, is violated when typecasting in C?

Comment: @GRC That discussion wasn't about casting in general, but about casting a `void *`.  That's not the case In OP's example.

Comment: @larsks: In C, casting to/from `void *` is strongly discouraged. You might be thinking of C++ where it is required due to type-checking (the C standard explicitly allows implicit conversion, so casting might hide a conflict with non-void type). But that has nothing to do with casting other types as in the question - in that aspect you are right. One just should very well know about the implications.

Comment: @GRC: You confuse some things. As given in the other comments, there are very good reasons not to cast `void *` to/from other pointers (and actually none to cast), but in C you hardly can avoid casts completely for any non-trivial program - unless you disable important warnings (don't!). At least the standard library will have some casts. Point is, however, you have to very well know what you are actually doing and be aware of **all** implications of a cast (aliasing, alignment, const-correctness, re-interpretation, etc.).

Comment: @GRC "it is against standard to cast in C" -- Please don't make ridiculous and false authoritative statements about languages that you clearly know nothing about. -- Former member of X3J11 (C Standard committee)

Comment: @GRC " it is REALLY BAD or SCARRY [sic] look here" -- no one there said anything like that. The closest was Rup's tongue-in-cheek comment, " you're invoking the wrath of the C-tag regulars. (Not that I mind.)"

Comment: @GRG a) So what if someone told you something in chat? Given what you've written here, odds are you didn't understand him. b) You said that it violates the C standard. **You're wrong.** And the claim is silly on its face ... the C standard would not both provide a facility and ban it. c) The reality is that you should avoid casts when possible, and it's usually possible, but not always.

Comment: Guys got in touch with my professor, and this makes perfect sense to me, by standard "Converting form wider to narrower types are not illegal but you might loose data." another part says "Conversion form narrower to wider types is automatic". This implies that you do not need cast in case like `char c = 5; int a = c` at all. In case where you are loosing data, as a programmer you should know your consequences. Casting is more for OOP languages where it is MUST, since int and char are treated as an object. But anyway sorry to be rude but I am right it is against standard to cast in C!!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("value of a: %d  value of b: %d\n", *( &teste), *((char*) &teste + offsetof(abcd, b)) );
```

This passes `teste` by value, which takes more space than a single int.  The 2nd `%d` will probably be getting input from some of the bytes of the first arg.  Compiler warnings make this clear:

```
$ clang-3.5 -Wall  bad-printf.c -O3 
bad-printf.c:12:48: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'abcd' (aka 'struct abcd') [-Wformat]
    printf("value of a: %d  value of b: %d\n", *( &teste), *((char*) &teste + offsetof(abcd, b)) );
                        ~~                     ^~~~~~~~~~

$ gcc -Wall  bad-printf.c -O3 
bad-printf.c: In function ‘main’:
bad-printf.c:12:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘abcd’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("value of a: %d  value of b: %d\n", *( &teste), *((char*) &teste + offsetof(abcd, b)) );
     ^

$ ./a.out 
value of a: 5  value of b: 0

$ uname -a
Linux tesla 3.19.0-22-generic #22-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 16 17:15:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It also passes a one-byte character to `printf`, as the 3rd arg (2nd arg after the format string).  The other bytes in the register (or on the stack, if you compiled for obsolete 32bit x86) may be leftover from something else.

Check the assembly output.  You'll probably find a one-byte load from `&abcd.b`, leaving the other bytes untouched.

You've told printf (by using `%d`) that you passed it a full `int`.  If you only wanted to print an 8bit integer (so it wouldn't treat the padding as data), you need a size prefix to your format specifier.

Answer (score 0):

printf %d but you pass sturct adcd, this is a undefined action, result is undefined,it should consider printf.c implement.

my code：

```
 typedef struct abcd{
        int a,b;
            double c,d;
}abcd;

int main()
{
    abcd teste = {.a = 3, .b = 5, .c = 7, .d = 9}; 
    printf("value of a: %d  //value of b:  %d\n",*( (char*) &teste), *((char*) &teste + offsetof(abcd, b)) );
    printf("%d\n", offsetof(abcd, b));
    printf("value of a: %p  value of b: %p\n", ( &teste), ((char*) &teste + offsetof(abcd, b)) );
    printf("value of a: %d  value of b: %d\n", teste, *((char*) &teste));
    printf("value of a: %p  value of b: %p\n", &teste, ((char*) &teste));
    printf("value of a: %d  value of b: %d\n", teste, *((char*) &teste));
    //No casting to (char*) in value of a
    return 0;
}
result：
value of a: 3  //value of b:  5
4
value of a: 0x7fff86f203b0  value of b: 0x7fff86f203b4
value of a: 3  value of b: -2114388464
value of a: 0x7fff86f203b0  value of b: 0x7fff86f203b0
value of a: 3  value of b: -2114388464
```

undfined process cause unkonwn result